# script/console output in a tabular fashion like railscast

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In [railscast](http://railscasts.com) when Ryan uses script/console he gets the output in a nicely formatted tabular fashion. Does anyone know what gem does that magic for you?

Comment: It's linked to on the page for every Railscast that uses it and Ryan usually even mentions it in the video itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Hirb](http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb)